# What's going on in this Guice example?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

I've got the following code example.

```
public interface Calculator {
    public int compute(int a);
}

public class Adder implements Calculator {
    private int n = 0;

    @Override public int compute(int a) {
        int result = a + n;
        ++n;
        return result;
    }
}

public class X {@Inject public void run(Calculator c) {
        System.out.println(c.compute(500));
    }
}
public class FirstModule extends AbstractModule {@Override protected void configure() {
        bind(Calculator.class).to(Adder.class);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new FirstModule());
    X x1 = inj.getInstance(X.class);
    x1.run(inj.getInstance(Calculator.class));
    X x2 = inj.getInstance(X.class);
    x2.run(inj.getInstance(Calculator.class));
    System.out.println(x1 == x2);
}
```

I expected the output to be:

```
500
500
False
```

and instead it is:

```
500
500
500
500
False
```

It seems that the instantiation lines (like `X x1 = inj.getInstance(X.class);`) execute the `run()` method. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Guice indeed does call `run`, because you tell it to:

```
public class X { /* here -> */ @Inject public void run(Calculator c) {
        System.out.println(c.compute(500));
    }
}
```

The `@Inject` annotation of the run method makes Guice think that this is a setter, so it injects a calculator instance into your class using `run`, when it injects the members during instance creation.

See [documentation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectionPoints).

Guice does not only inject constructors, annotated with `@Inject` but also fields annotated with `@Inject` and methods annotated with `@Inject`.

For example (besides the timing/order) these examples lead to the same result, namely foo being injected:

```
class ConstructorInjection {
    private String foo;

    @Inject public ConstructorInjection(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}

class FieldInjection {
    @Inject private String foo;

    // default constructor not needed in this case
}

class MethodInjection {
    private String foo;

    // default constructor not needed in this case

    @Inject
    public void setFoo(String foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

Note that Guice does not imply any naming conventions on methods to inject (so the setter `setFoo` could have been named `run` or anything else as well. Guice will inject all methods annotated with `@Inject`.

You are basically using the third way (MethodInjection) which will cause Guice to call `run` when the instance is created.

As Girish shows in his/her answer, you'd have to use constructor injection (or field injection) in your case, have a field for the calculator in your class and remove the parameter from the run method.

Comment: I'm still confused. Why would guice inject a non constructor method without it being called directly?

Answer (score 1):

@Inject will execute the contructor/method you have specified. Correct way of using it is with constructor to inject Calc instance.

```
    interface Calculator
{
    public int compute(int a);
}

class Adder implements Calculator
{
    private int n = 0;

    @Override
    public int compute(int a)
    {
        int result = a + n;
        ++n;
        return result;
    }
}

class X
{
    private Calculator c;

    @Inject
    public X(Calculator c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run(Calculator c)
    {
        System.out.println(c.compute(500));
    }
}
class FirstModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        bind(Calculator.class).to(Adder.class);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new FirstModule());
        X x1 = inj.getInstance(X.class);
        x1.run(inj.getInstance(Calculator.class));
        X x2 = inj.getInstance(X.class);
        x2.run(inj.getInstance(Calculator.class));
        System.out.println(x1 == x2);
    }
```

Output:

500 
500 
false